# OOP inheritance memory initialization

Tags: oop, inheritance

When you're instantiating an object of a class that inherits from a parent class the constructor calls the superclasses constructor in most langiages I know and my question is: when the superclasse's constructor is called there will effectively be an object of that type in memory, but we're creating an object of the subclass with(in this example) additional values to add to the object so how is that accomplished in memory? Is it added to the original object? Are the contents of the original object copied into a new object with space for all the variables? Or is it something completely different?

A different question that just occured to me, are class variables, like in java, kept in the data segment of the program in memory? How are classes, not the objects, stored in memory for that matter?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to know that? anyway, it depends on engine and/or compiler, so you have to check it's code

Comment: @vladkras I don't need to know, I just want to. If it's implementation specific could you give me an example of an implementation idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know how engine works, but I know how to test memory usage in PHP. Both scripts

```
class base {
    public function __construct() {

    }
}

$start_memory = memory_get_usage();
$object = new base;
echo memory_get_usage() - $start_memory;
```

and

```
class base {
    public function __construct() {

    }
}
class derived extends base {
    public function __construct() {

    }
}

$start_memory = memory_get_usage();
$object = new derived;
echo memory_get_usage() - $start_memory;
```

return the same value. It means there'is only one instance in memory, not parent + it's child, when class is extended

phpfiddles: [1st script](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/3mv-2pg), [2nd script](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/zh2-gw8)

Answer (score 0):

Classed are code that define its object, so they are in Code Segment of program. And all class variables are in data segment.

And when we create an object of subclass, first its parents' object are created and it is extended for subclass members. That's why subclass object has all members of its parent class.

Comment: it's obvious, you just writing the basics from php tutorial (section "classes")